# Make a popup window appear on/near the image I clicked on

Tags: android, popup

I have really been struggling with this and no matter what I do I keep getting the popup window to appear where I don't want it.  I want it to appear either where I click/touch or have a bit of an offset to where I touch when I tap on an image.

This is my method that I have set in my xml for when the image is tapped :

```
public void loadPopUp(View v) {

    popUp.showAtLocation((View) v.getParent().getParent(),
            Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 0);
    popUp.update(v.getLeft(), "No clue what to put here", 300, 80);

}
```

2 Things about pop up windows that I am just unsure about.  Should I be making my first parameter of showAtLocation be a root view so I am encompassing the whole layout instead of just the layout the view is inside?

Also I have "no clue what to put here" because I just cannot get my y coordinate to work.  My x (v.getLeft()) is fine because my app does not move left and right, just up and down is where I am struggling to get where the user tapped on the image.

XML :

```
<ScrollView xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:tag="small" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/godOverview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/godItemRowOneLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/godItem1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/god_recommended_item_1"
            android:onClick="loadPopUp"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/godItem2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/god_recommended_item_2"
            android:onClick="loadPopUp"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/godItem3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/god_recommended_item_3"
            android:onClick="loadPopUp"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Where exactly do you want it and why aren't you using `v` instead of `v.getParent().getParent()` in `showAtLocation()`?

Answer (score 0):

> Should I be making my first parameter of showAtLocation be a root view so I am encompassing the whole layout instead of just the layout the view is inside?

No. This is the view that the popup should be anchored to, so it should be the one that was touched to trigger the popup.

> Also I have "no clue what to put here" because I just cannot get my y
>   coordinate to work.

You're overcomplicating it. If you've anchored it with the first call, you don't need to set the x and y, just the height and width (which you should be calculating as a function of the screen density, by the way).

NOTE:

PopupMenu has more intelligent behavior as far as anchoring to the view, but it *only* shows menus. You can browse the source code to see how they handle layout, though.